# How to handle the PHP response from jQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Currently, I cant access the return data from my jquery ajax. Actually, I dont even know if I am sending any data at all? I just need to send data from a form with JSON to php, and get the response as an array.

Thanks for the help.

HTML/JS/jQuery

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function () { 
                var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var postData = {
                    username: uname,
                    password: pword
                };
                alert(uname);

                $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: postData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type='text' id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <br />
        <input type='password' id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'username' => $_GET['username'],
    'password' => $_GET['password']
));
```

Comment: what are you seeing in your alerts? you may need to use `JSON.parse` somewhere in there to convert the JSON into usable content. And, have you tried using a tool such as Firebug to see what you're sending out and getting back?

Comment: Actually, now I just made some edits and saw that I am getting a response back, but it's returning [object object]. How do I convert the array from JSON back to JS? do I use JSON.parse?

Comment: @copilot0910: You might need to call `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: try `alert(data.username)`...I don't use jQuery, so I'm not certain that it's already been parsed...so if that doesn't work, try (in your success function) `var received_data=JSON.parse(data); alert(received_data.username);`

Comment: @icanc JSON.parse(data) will not alert anything. I tried just alerting data and data.username. Both show nothing. What I'm wondering is if a null value is returned. Also, I added async: false, so at least it alerts something now.

Comment: @copilot0910: How are you debugging? Did you try `var d = JSON.parse(data);` then call `alert(d.username)`?  Try this inside `success:`.

Comment: I set a variable equal to the json parse. Also, every time I do try it inside success:. Still returns no data. I am wondering, does my php return null values? I mean, if the jQuery should be working, does this mean the PHP is returning no value and jQuery has nothing to alert?

Comment: @icanc Now, when adding return false, as the answer suggested, I am receiving a response. The username and password are being echoed back, but when I try to alert them, they dont alert. When I dont use JSON.parse, the results are null, while when I use it, it wont alert them. What do I do?

Comment: @copilot0910: I'd suggest to step through the code in Chrome's debugger or Firebug.  Also since you're doing a ajax call, I would suggest using `type="button"` and using an `onclick` handler to make life easier.

Comment: I'm looking at the response in firebug and see that the response is coming back as expected, but I cant alert the results. Also, if I try to alert without parsing the JSON, the results come back as null.

Comment: One more note. When I use JSON.parse(data), firebug says that the results are GET, not POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a handler for the submit event but it seems that you forgot to return false in order to stop the basic submit process.

A form with an empty action will POST data in the same page (your initial PHP page), so the AJAX call back is sent but just after, you are posting again with basic way.

Add a `return false` at the end of the function  (just after your AJAX call) and then your form will not be submitted, the AJAX will be sent and you will see the response.

If you are using Firefox, install Firebug and look at the Network tab to see your request sent by the Ajax call and check your JSON response.

Good luck.